# se insertan datos en diferentes columnas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

buen dia eh estado desarollando un crud pero al registrar los usuarios me los guarda en la columna de correo es decir el nombre tiene registrado el correo pero no veo que me aya guardado el nombre ya que el usuario y el password si me los dejo guardar

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        include ("configuracion.php");
        $conexion = new mysqli ($server,$user,$pass,$bd);

        if (!$conexion) {

            $msg="Conexión imposible. Revise las credenciales de conexión";    
        } else {

            $usuario=!empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
            $repassword=!empty($_POST['repassword']) ? $_POST['repassword'] : NULL;


            $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
            $nombre=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;

            if($usuario && $password && $repassword && $nombre) { 
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

                $rec = $conexion->query($sql); 
                /*
                    Es mejor usar un booleano directamente
                */
                $verificar_usuario = FALSE;

                 while($result = $rec->fetch_object()) { 
                    if($result->usuario == $usuario) { 
                        $verificar_usuario = TRUE; 
                        /*
                             En caso de seguir con esta lógica, lo cual es ilógico
                             habría que salir del bucle con break cuando la condición se cumpla
                             sino seguirá leyendo las otras filas sin necesidad
                        */
                            break; 
                    }
                } 

if($verificar_usuario) { 
if($password == $repassword) { 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES
                ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')";

        if ($conexion->query($sql) && $conexion->affected_rows > 0) {
        $msg="Usted se ha registrado correctamente.";
    } else {
        $msg="Error en la inserción";
    }
} else { 
    $msg="Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente."; 
} 
} else {

$msg="Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente."; 
} 

} else {
$msg="Por favor llene todos los campos. Faltan datos en el POST";
}
}

} else {
$msg="No hay POST enviar";  
}
/*
Al final imprimimos $msg
*/
echo $msg;
```

aca esta  el form que manda a llamar la base de datos phplogin entonces no se por que los esta insertando en en la columna correo y por que no me esta guardando el nombre lo demas no hay problema si lo cacha

me pide agregar mas detalles pero creo que ya es todo lo que le esta pasando al insert entonces no se que mas podria ponerle para saber por que me sale este error

```
    <form  method="POST" action="conexion.php" >
        <fieldset>
        <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>
        </label>
        <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-danger">
        <i class="ace-icon fa f

    a-lightbulb-o"></i>
        <span class="bigger-110">Enviar</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div><!-- /.regis

tro de usuario -->



    <div class="toolbar center">
    <a href="#" data-target="#login-box" class="back-to-login-link">
    Regresar al Login
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
    </div><!-- /.forgot-box -->

    <div id="signup-box" class="signup-box widget-box no-border">
    <div class="widget-body">
    <div class="widget-main">
    <h4 class="header green lighter bigger">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users blue"></i>
    Registro de Nuevos Usuarios
    </h4>
    <div class="space-6"></div>
    <p>Ingresa los datos solicitados acontinuacion: </p>
    <form action="conexion.php" method="POST" >
    <fieldset>
    <label class="block clearfix">
    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo"  required />
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users"></i>
    </span>
    </label>

    <label class="block clearfix">
    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" placeholder="correo"  required />
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
    </span>
    </label>
    <label class="block clearfix">
    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario"  required />
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
    </span>
    </label>
    <label class="block clearfix">
    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"  required />
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
    </span>
    </label>

    <label class="block clearfix">
    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repassword" placeholder="Repetir password" />
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-retweet"></i>
    </span>
    </label>

    <label class="block">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
    <span class="lbl">
    Acepto los
    <a href="#">Terminos de Uso</a>
    </span>
    </label>
    <div class="space-24"></div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="reset" class="width-30 pull-left btn btn-sm">
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh"></i>
    <span class="bigger-110">Reset</span>
    </button>

    <button type="submit" name="enviar"   class="width-65 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <span class="bigger-110">Registrar</span>
    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right"></i>
    </button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hola. Ademá del error indicado en la respuesta estás validando al revés. `if($verificar_usuario) { // grabas debiendo salir o actualizar; }else{ // debes validar password confirmado y crear registro }`

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está en esta linea

```
$nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
$nombre=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;
```

Primero le estas asignando en la variable nombre el nombre que llega por método POST, pero después le estas reasignando su valor cambiándolo por el correo.

Deberías dejarlo así:

```
$nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
$correo=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;
```

Comment: a toy @/()/%&/

pero ahora cuando guardo uno nuevo me sale que ya etsoy registrado y cuando registro uno que si esta me lo vuelve a registrar

Comment: y gracias grcias

Comment: @robertomendoza me parece que tendrías que poner el `if` de este modo: `if(!$verificar_usuario) { `  así insertará cuando no exista el usuario. De todos modos, sería mejor que simplifiques con `WHERE` como te comenté en otra pregunta.

Comment: si si si 
me lo dejaste asi verdad 
if($verificar_usuario) { seria este el que lo agrego

if($password == $repassword) {

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @A.Cedano, deberias negar la condición con este signo "!" dejándola de este modo "if(!$verificar_usuario)"

Comment: Hola @robertomendoza mira el comentario que te dejé en la pregunta. Validas al revés!

Comment: ya quedo gracias y perdon me esta costando trabajo aprender

Comment: @robertomendoza lee los comentarios en el código, te ayudarán a entenderlo. La lógica es que si dentro del `while` encuentra al usuario la variable `$verificar_usuario` adquiere el valor  `TRUE` y sale del `while`. Si no lo encuentra la variable será `FALSE` como se estableció al principio (antes del `while`). Luego aquí preguntas en negativo, que es lo que significa el símbolo `!`: **`if(!$verificar_usuario) {`** significa *si `$verificar_usuario` es `FALSE`* ...   y si le quitas ese símbolo significaría lo contrario: `$verificar_usuario` es `TRUE`